# Зачем нужна эквивалентность?

Tags: c++

Есть равенство (equality) == .

Есть эквивалентность(equivalence) !(a < b) && !(b < a).

Не очень понимаю, зачем нужна эквивалентность?

Comment: Чтобы  было достаточно иметь только operator<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что не всё, что эквивалентно — равно. Самый банальный пример: строка «Привет» эквивалентна «привет», если нас интересует их порядок в некотором списке, где не учитывается регистр. Но, очевидно, что эти строки не равны. Есть множество примеров различных сущностей, которые считаются эквивалентными, но не являются равными. В топологии таких примеров полно, например.

Answer (score 2):

Наглядный пример, кроме выше сказанного:      `std::map<key_type, mapped_type>` 
Сравнивает свои  `key_type` компаратором   `std::less<key_type>`.  Чтобы узнать, есть такой ключ, он может делать только сравнение типа   `!(a < b) && !(b < a).`